# Javascript regex filetype crashes chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a weird issue with trying to match a url containing an image file extension on the end. The regex im using is pretty simple (has no url validation as such but as a first iteration will do for now).

I've set up a fiddle which should explain it better than i can in words. See the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwat2/1/

Notes:

1. Make sure your testing in chrome
2. Make sure you have task manager open for chrome (settings icon > tools > task manager)
3. Run the jsfiddle, the regex without the file extension match on the end will fire 3 seconds after you copy the url into the textarea and will be ok), 3 seconds after that the one WITH the file extension match will fire, if it's affecting you, the text will not change to fired and you will see jsfiddle eat up CPU in the task manager

Hopefully someone can explain what is going on here, i've run the regex in PHP and in expresso and it doesn't have any issues so i dont think its stuck in some sort of regex internal loop or anything.

Thanks for any help

Edit: Heres a slimmed down version which more closely resembles my use of it in my application (ive removed the timers and other helpers from the first fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/A96Mw/1/

Comment: If you remove these intervals and every-second-matching and leave a single `val.match(broken_regex)`, CPU consumption doesn't reach 100%. Just saying

Comment: I'll test that in jsfiddle, however the interval timer is there to help people follow it better. My application does not use a interval and fires the regex immediately and still crashes.

Comment: The regexp is not properly escaped. Note that you need to escape slashes only in regex literals, but backslashes in string literals!

Comment: Ok i've added a new fiddle (see bottom of question) and my CPU still gets eaten up in that fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a case of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) because of this expression: `(?:[^ ]+)+`. Not sure why the first one works while the second doesn't.

The regexes you want are

```
url = new RegExp("https?://(?:[^ ]+)\\.", "i")
// or
url = /https?:\/\/(?:[^ ]+)+\./i
```

and

```
imgurl = new RegExp("https?://(?:[^ ]+)\\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)", "i")
// or
imgurl = /https?:\/\/(?:[^ ]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)/i
```

Comment: Well that worked! Thanks Bergi, so what is the difference between `\\.` and `\.` in the RegExp? (Just trying to understand how it works, i guess there are some differences i need to learn between PHP and JS regex)

Comment: None. Yet, when creating a Regex from a string you will need to escape backslashes in the string literal (like quotes), while in regex literals you will need to escape the slashes.

Comment: Ah right ok, that makes sense. Whilst i have you, is it down to personal preference as to whether to use regex literals vs RegExp(), or is there reasons for and against both?

Comment: Sometimes you need to create regexes from strings, e.g. when dynamically assemling them or from user input. In the most other situations I find literals easier to read. I'm quite sure that there are no (big) performance issues; their behaviour is the same.

Comment: ah of course, that makes sense. Well im glad thats fixed, been trying to figure it out for ages. Cheers for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Two words: [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html):

```
(?:[^ ]+)+\.
```

is a useless construct - `[^ ]+\.` matches exactly the same and is not prone to backtracking.

By nesting the two quantifiers, you'll get exponential increases in runtime on strings that don't end in a period. Some browsers may choose to abort the regex match after a couple million cycles, others (like Chrome, it seems) will keep on trying.

Comment: +1 for explanation. I believe this should be report as (possible) bug with Chrome...